# Flash: text antialiasing bug in first line

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, text, antialiasing

[image: This is the problem]

As you can see the letter P has an antialiasing problem.

I have tried changin the AntiAliasType.ADVANCED to NORMAL ... with the same results.

Maybe if there was some padding-top property... but there isn't.

Any ideas how to solve that?

Comment: It's a TextField class. I put it there dynamically by code... how can I know if it's classic or TLF?

Answer (score 0):

You could tune the sharpness and thickness of the textfield:

```
var textfield:TextField = new TextField;
textfield.antiAliasType = AntiAliasType.ADVANCED;
textfield.sharpness = 100;
textfield.thickness = 100;
```

Understanding your font, embed and text format, any scaling, stage quality, and sizing would help; as would seeing your programmatic implementation in code.  Check your TextField bounds - assure appropriate height.

Per anti alias, `AntiAliasType.ADVANCED` should yield higher quality; however, is not optimal when approaching larger font sizes over 48pt.

Answer (score 0):

Try placing the textfield in a sprite with a solid color rectangle (same as the main background), advanced antialiased textfields without a solid background may cause render issues.

Comment: Nope... it seems the text is a bit clearer but still got that bug.

Comment: Did you check if the same font renders correctly in different rows? (other than the first, as multiline textfield) - if so, you cold add "\n" before the 'P' to break a new row and position the textfield accordingly, if you only use it once as in a logo this could be an acceptable workaround.

* The voodoo as3 requires sometimes..

Comment: Yes, the problem only occurs in the first row. I already considered that hack, but I will only use it as a last resource...

Answer (score 0):

Check if your text field coordinates (x, y) are in full pixels (integer numbers).

Comment: Also check all ancestors (parent, parent's parent, and so on). You may also check if the scale of all ancestors is equal 1.

Comment: Yes, everything is a full pixels, and scale is 1